# Imagem de fundo não é replicada nas demais páginas ao usar funcão onChange

Tags: javascript, html

Pessoal estou tentando selecionar uma imagem de fundo de acordo com opção selecionada em uma função `onChange`, mas acontece que ela (a imagem) só é aplicada na primeira página, se eu **`NÃO`** usar a função `onChange` para o endereço da imagem mostra em todas as páginas normalmente, o problema se dá ao implementar a opção de select e função onChange, segue codigo e imagens com e sem a função que estou usando:

> **SEM** a função:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**COM** a função:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Inspecionando os elementos verifiquei o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código:

> script da função

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    document.getElementById("imagem").src = "img/gab" + x + ".png"
}
</script>
```

> CSS

```
    <style>
html { font-size: 12pt; 

}

.folha { align:center;background-color: #ccc; padding: 0.5em;


 }
.a4_vertical { width: 793px; height: 1122px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 }
.a4_horizontal { width: 1122px; height: 793px; 
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

#container figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 94px;
  left: 87px;
  color: black;
}
<title>FOLHA DE RESPOSTA</title>
</head>

<body>
```

> Select com onChange

```
<div align="center">
    <select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
      <option value="1">1 Questão
      <option value="2">2 Questões
      <option value="3">3 Questões
      <option value="4">4 Questões
    </select>

</div>
```

> Aqui é onde eu chamo a imaegm de fundo, se no lugar de id="imagem" eu usar `src=...` funciona mas preciso usar um `select` com `onChange`

Assim  funciona:

```
   <div><img align="center" src="img/gab1.png" width="600px" height="auto" /></div>
```

Assim **`não`** Funciona:

```
   <div><img align="center" id="imagem" width="600px" height="auto" /></div>
```

> **Edit**

Bastou adicionar isso à resposta do Fernando e funcionou pra mim

```
window.onload=function(){
       //código aqui
}
```

Comment: rsrs Corrigido kkkkk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Miguel, o conceito de ID é ser um identificador, algo único que separa uma coisa do resto.

Se você quer ter vários elementos com o mesmo ID, então o que você quer é identificar um grupo de elementos, e não um único elemento.

Para identificar um grupo de elementos, usar classes é o recomendado.

Veja a diferença:

```js
let imagens = document.getElementById("bg-page");
let select = document.querySelector("#select-gabarito");

select.addEventListener("change", function() {
 imagens.src = this.value;
});
```

```css
.paginas {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #CCC;
}

#bg-page {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 210px;
  height: 297px;
  outline: 1px solid #888;
}
```

```html
<select id="select-gabarito">
  <option value="https://via.placeholder.com/210x297/ff00ff/ffffff">#ff00ff</option>
  <option value="https://via.placeholder.com/210x297/00ffff/ffffff">#00ffff</option>
  <option value="https://via.placeholder.com/210x297/ff0000/ffffff">#ff0000</option>
  <option value="https://via.placeholder.com/210x297/00ff00/ffffff">#00ff00</option>
</select>

<hr>

<div class="paginas">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/210x297/" id="bg-page">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/210x297/" id="bg-page">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/210x297/" id="bg-page">
</div>
```

Agora usando o atributo `class` para pegar um grupo de elementos (veja [`Document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) ou [`Document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)).

```js
let imagens = document.querySelectorAll(".bg-page");
let select = document.querySelector("#select-gabarito");

select.addEventListener("change", function() {
 let novo_src = this.value;
 imagens.forEach(function(img) {
   img.src = novo_src;
  });
});
```

```css
.paginas {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #CCC;
}

.bg-page {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 210px;
  height: 297px;
  outline: 1px solid #888;
}
```

```html
<select id="select-gabarito">
  <option value="https://via.placeholder.com/210x297/ff00ff/ffffff">#ff00ff</option>
  <option value="https://via.placeholder.com/210x297/00ffff/ffffff">#00ffff</option>
  <option value="https://via.placeholder.com/210x297/ff0000/ffffff">#ff0000</option>
  <option value="https://via.placeholder.com/210x297/00ff00/ffffff">#00ff00</option>
</select>

<hr>

<div class="paginas">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/210x297/"class="bg-page">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/210x297/"class="bg-page">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/210x297/"class="bg-page">
</div>
```

Comment: Desculpe minha ignorância, como fica esse código em meu código?

Comment: Não precisa se desculpar, o site serve justamente para aprendermos. Estou no celular agora, então não vou conseguir trabalhar bem na explicação, mas você precisaria utilizar classes nas imagens e seleciona-las como no meu exemplo. Quando eu estiver perto do meu PC eu formulo melhor a explicação

Comment: Tem de fazer algo mais nesse código, testei aqui e não funciona, só copiei e colei, mas nada acontece

Comment: Olha [este JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c7xemp1h/) e vê se isso te ajuda.

Comment: Cara funcionou perfeitamente! só precisei implementar um linha pra resolver um erro que estava ocorrendo, mas ficou muito show, vou editar sua resposta

Comment: Edita a sua pergunta. Não minha resposta.
Minha resposta é para mostrar o conceito, a não ser que tenho algum erro no conceito.

Comment: O comum é colocar um **EDIT** no fim da sua pergunta com os ajustes que você usou da minha resposta para solucionar seu problema.

Comment: Dava erro na execução, editei aí, dá uma olhada

Comment: Sua edição quebrou o exemplo. Como disse, coloca na sua pergunta a alteração do código que você fez. Assim minha resposta serve para explicar um conceito e na sua pergunta têm o conceito aplicado.

Comment: Vou retirar a edição

Comment: Já retirei, fica tranquilo. E também editei meus códigos para que fiquei mais parecidos com o que você precisa.

Answer (score 1):

Vamos lá.

Seu problema acontece pois você replica vários IDs iguais dentro da mesma página. A função se refere ao ID por si só, não sabe diferenciar qual dos IDs você quer. A solução é colocar o `onchange()` dentro da div de cada página, e mudar sua função `JS` para se referir à `class` daquela div, e não da página.

```js
function myFunction(pagina) {
  var x = pagina.querySelector(".mySelect").value;
  pagina.querySelector(".imagem").src = "img/gab" + x + ".png";
}
```

```html
<div onchange="myFunction(this)">
    <select class="mySelect">
     <option value="1">1 Questão
     <option value="2">2 Questões
     <option value="3">3 Questões
     <option value="4">4 Questões
    </select>
    <img class="imagem">
</div>
<div onchange="myFunction(this)">
     <select class="mySelect">
       <option value="1">1 Questão
       <option value="2">2 Questões
       <option value="3">3 Questões
       <option value="4">4 Questões
    </select>
    <img class="imagem">
</div>
<div onchange="myFunction(this)">
     <select class="mySelect">
       <option value="1">1 Questão
       <option value="2">2 Questões
       <option value="3">3 Questões
       <option value="4">4 Questões
    </select>
    <img class="imagem">
</div>
```

Ou seja. Você vai mudar o `onchange` para a div que está ao redor de cada página, colocar o valor `this` como parâmetro da função, e modificar seu código para achar o ID dentro daquela div apenas. Fiz o teste aqui e funcionou, tente fazer no seu.

Comment: Não votei negativo, mas a sua resposta está errada, embora possa funcionar. Um `id`deve ser único na página.

Comment: Sim, eu sei que deve, mas no caso dele, como a página é replicada várias vezes dentro da mesma janela, não há como mudar todas as IDs e fazer uma função diferente para cada página sabendo que não existe necessáriamente um limite de quantidade de páginas.

Comment: Pronto, editei os IDs para classes. Não tinha me tocado que poderia ter feito isso, já que no código dele eram todos IDs. Obrigado pela correção.

Comment: Matheus, o downvote era meu por conta dos ids. Ia comentar aqui em breve para a correção. Downvote retirado já, porém fica atento porque o `querySelector` pega apenas o primeiro achado, enquanto o `querySelectorAll` pega todos os elementos encontrados, retornando um `NodeList`. Aí é só fazer um laço e modificar.

Comment: Fernando, no caso dele, precisa realmente ser interligado cada `select` com cada imagem, por isso o `querySelector`. Precisa selecionar um só por vez mesmo. Obrigado também por chamar minha atenção sobre isso. Seria possível fazer desta forma que você disse, mas acho que daria mais trabalho comparando as duas listas, se pode ser comparado cada elemento de cada página separadamente.

Comment: Não quero um select cada págima, apenas um select ho topo pra aplicar a imagem pra todas as páginas

Comment: Eu tinha entendido que você queria vincular cada um com cada select. Vou editar

Comment: Agradecer aos que dispuseram de tempo pra tentar resolver o problema, Vlw @MáttheusSpoo Sam